# NodeJs : Get image stream

Tags: node.js, postman, busboy

I am trying to read image stream in my web api.

Following is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var Busboy = require('busboy');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
var busboy = new Busboy({
        headers: request.headers
    });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
        file.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
        });
        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
        });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

When I test the above post endpoint using postman, Nothing happens.
It seems that the busboy.on is never called/triggered.

Busboy npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy#readme

Following is my request. Traced through fiddler.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 879585
Postman-Token: 1defded8-01ff-eb6e-4afa-c49f63b477db
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySrX3beIdojsVD2nB
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4

------WebKitFormBoundarySrX3beIdojsVD2nB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="Chrysanthemum.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are already using busboy but I still recommend you to try [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and stuff like boundry&multipart wouldn't bother you.

But if you'd like to wrap busboy yourself, [these code](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/lib/make-middleware.js) in multer would also be useful.

Also remember to check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174296/postman-multipart-form-data-error-missing-start-boundary). Maybe you override the Content-Type in postman, which is not necessary.